# create Panel at Pandas by multi-level dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I am a new to python and pandas.
And I found myself that I have a problem in creating Panel or multi-index DataFrame at pandas.

The fact is that I have a multi-level dictionary, currently three level where the final value is an integer, and I want it's key in each level to be an corresponding index for Panel ,that correspond Panel's item , major-axis,and minor-axis to my dict's first, second, third level. When I create one from my dictionary, the index is not match though.
Here is my dictionary.

```
d={'item1':{'major0':{'minor0':1,
                      'minor1':2},
            'major1':{'minor0':3,
                      'minor1':4}
           },
   'item2':{'major0':{'minor0':5,
                      'minor1':6},
            'major1':{'minor0':7,
                      'minor1':8}
           }
  }
```

Is there any simple way to do this. I have look through Pandas tutorial and just not saw any function support of this.

Comment: Can you give a small complete sample of your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the swap_axes method after construction:

```
In [1]: p = pd.Panel(d)

In [2]: p.swapaxes()
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: item1 to item2
Major_axis axis: major0 to major1
Minor_axis axis: minor0 to minor1
```

It's worth mentioning the `from_dict` Panel method, which allows you to pass an orient (but apparently only items/minor are allowed, whilst you want to do major...):

```
In [11]: pd.Panel.from_dict(d, orient='minor')  # default orient is items
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 2 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: major0 to major1
Major_axis axis: minor0 to minor1
Minor_axis axis: item1 to item2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this counts as a *simple* way, as collapsing the dictionary is definitely something you'll have to do by hand, but:

```
# Collapse the first two levels of keys into tuples
# The dict comprehension could (and maybe should) be written
# with standard for loops
d_collapsed = {(outer_k, inner_k): inner_v for outer_k in d 
               for inner_k, inner_v in d[outer_k].items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_collapsed)
# Now unpack the tuples again
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
df
Out[18]: 
         item1           item2        
        major0  major1  major0  major1
minor0       1       3       5       7
minor1       2       4       6       8
```

Comment: genius, I from here learned something about multiIndex usage. the pandas tutorial just give too much info to digest and quick learning.